# Matlab: Easiest/Efficient way to extend each data in a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, replace, repeat

If I have a matrix `P` of size `3975 x 12` with link to download given below. The number of rows in each column of `P` which are **not** `NaN` are given by `3975/sizesBlock`, where `sizesBlock` is `[1    3   5   15  25  53  75  159 265 795 1325    3975]`. How can I replace all those columns containing `NaN` such that each number in column `j` repeats itself by `sizesBlock(j)` times. Is there any fast/efficient way of doing this? Thanks.

Matrix `P` can be downloaded [from here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B0g3l3PoZi9lWWdSQWtOVWRQQTA/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: link is not working for me.

Comment: It's working when I am trying..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
iSeries  = 1;
for iBlock = sizesBlock
    temp = repmat(P(1:(sizesBlock(end)/iBlock), iSeries), iBlock, 1);
    temp = reshape(reshape(temp, (sizesBlock(end)/iBlock), iBlock)', sizesBlock(end), 1);
    modifiedP(:, iSeries) = temp;
    iSeries = iSeries + 1;
end
```